# Need to escape white space before appending to url

Tags: jquery

This is the parameter portion of the string as I need it:

```
?parentId=PRICE&childId=%20LIST
```

This is the parameter portion as it is (Note the missing %20):

```
?parentId=PRICE&childId=LIST
```

Here is the function that gathers the data from two select boxes (#parentCodes and #childCodes):

```
            function ajaxCodeDetails(){
                $.getJSON(
                "manage-inventory-codes_codeDetails",
                {'parentId': $("#parentCodes").val(),
                    'childId': $("#childCodes").val()},
                renderDetails
            );
            }
```

How do I escape the result returned by val() before sending the request?

Comment: jQuery is escaping the data by default. If you don't get it the way you want to, it seems it is also trimming the data.

Comment: Yes it is trimming the leading space from "<option> LIST</option>", which is not acceptable.

Comment: I have to revise my comment. jQuery is not involved in this please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem with jQuery but with the form. It seems that leading and trailing spaces are ignored in the option's text (apparently, this is the normal behaviour of browsers, see below):

```
<select name="foo">
    <option> space</option>
    <option>space </option>
</select
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMkSu/1/)

but it works if they are set as `value`s:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value=" space"> space</option>
    <option value="space ">space </option>
</select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMkSu/2/)

---

The HTML specification has an interesting chapter about text, [in particular about white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1). There is says:

> In order to avoid problems with [SGML line break rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-line-breaks) and inconsistencies among extant implementations, authors should not rely on user agents to render white space immediately after a start tag or immediately before an end tag. Thus, authors, and in particular authoring tools, should write:
>
> ```
>   <P>We offer free <A>technical support</A> for subscribers.</P>
> ```
>
> and not:
>
> ```
>   <P>We offer free<A> technical support </A>for subscribers.</P>
> ```

So it seems that most browsers comply to this rule and ignore those spaces.

Comment: Since the data is obtained with JSON I was able to have the function that prepares the options simply add the required attribute which solved everything. Good eyes on finding my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `encodeURI()` function...

```
{'parentId': encodeUri($"#parentCodes").val(),
```

Comment: +1 for knowing when to use js over jquery. This is the best method when you are not able to let jquery handle encoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

HTML ignores leading and trailing white space within `<option>` tags.  Replace the leading and trailing space with `&nbsp;` so that it is correctly interpreted as a space by the browser.  You'll want to do this on the server.  Depending on the language, there is likely a method that will do this conversion for you.

Comment: +1 on account the solution would work, but since I'm getting JSON back felix klings solution is a little closer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ajaxCodeDetails(){                 
    $.getJSON(                 
        "manage-inventory-codes_codeDetails",{
            'parentId': $("#parentCodes").val().replace(/^\s+/g, ""),
            'childId': $("#childCodes").val().replace(/^\s+/g, "")
        },                 
        renderDetails             
    );             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to URL encode anything. jQuery will take care of this. `%20` means a url encoded space. So simply put a space in your textbox and it will be properly handled. Your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: It's from a select box. It is currently not taking care of it.

Comment: @Quaternion, that's probably due to how your combobox values look like. Your jQuery code is fine and should't be touched. It's exactly the correct way of sending parameters with the `$.getJSON` function. If you are not getting desired results either what is *desired* violates the HTTP specification or the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Firebug shows that the option value contains the word LIST with a leading white space.  If I append the first query string then I get the desired result, if I submit the second then I get the wrong result... clearly it is within the HTTP specification.